# Is using a header('location: ') enough to password protect a page?

Tags: php

Basically, I am checking to see if the user is logged in and if not I will use header('location: login.php') to redirect to the login page.

I am confused if the browser is actually redirecting or the server? If it is the browser then would it be possible for the user to prevent the browser from redirecting and view the contents of the page?

Comment: Just make sure you use `exit()` after your `header` call

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is not the browser that is re-directing, but php before anything is sent to the browser.

Just make sure you use `exit()` after your `header` call and that nothing is outputted to the browser before your `header` call.

Answer (score 0):

The server is redirecting.  The client browser gets directed to the page the server sends through the header modification.  The user is not able to prevent the redirection from the page, but **is** able to see content after that line of redirect code header('location: login.php');

```
// print to error log before and after header redirect to show code is executed after the redirect
error_log("before redirect");
header('location: login.php');

// this will get get executed.  To prevent, exit() script immediately after the header redirect
error_log("after redirect");
```

Comment: The last part is incorrect. Outputting a `Location:` header does **NOT** cause script execution to terminate! It will cause a browser to redirect immediately, but any actions performed by the script will still take place, and any output will be visible with various tools.

Answer (score 0):

If by "enough", you mean that the information will not be exposed to anyone who is not authenticated, even if they sniff the network traffic, then you must simply not send the information in the body of the response to any non-authenticated request.

Something like this should be enough:

```
header('location: login.php');
exit; // make sure not to echo anything in the body
```

It will cause the browser to receive an HTTP header and start a totally new request to login.php, while not revealing any of the sensitive info in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Well, keeping it simple, checking for specific variable and based on it , deciding for redirect / showing contents is okay...something like this will work for you..

```
if(your condition){
header(Location: login.php)
exit() or die() ;
}else{
show contents.....}
```